# Are the tokens counted after pre-processing or during the process of pre-processing only?

Tags: c, compiler-construction

During the time of pre-processing we usually scan all the `macros` but I am confused a bit that does the pre-processor also generates the tokens which are actually taken by the lexical analyzer and it further scans the input file ,

I have gone through this [link](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Tokenization.html)
 and it is mentioned that Preprocessing tokens fall into five broad classes: identifiers, preprocessing numbers, string literals, punctuators, and other,so are tokens generated during the state of pre-processing only or not ?

Comment: If this question is about the C preprocessor you might consider tagging it as such; C is not the only language with a preprocessor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of preprocessing is a stream of tokens.

Most tokens are produced prior to the macro expansion phase, but during macro expansion it is possible to create new tokens using the stringify (`#`) and token-concatenate (`##`) operators.

After preprocessing, many tokens need to be reanalyzed, and it is possible that some preprocessing tokens cannot be reanalyzed as valid tokens. For example, 2.3G is a preprocessing-number token, but it does not correspond to any valid numeric token. This will cause an error message.